# Call C++ function from AS3

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, flash, mfc, externalinterface

I´d like to call C++ functions from AS3(Desktop project) side.
My MFC project (Dialog Based) hosts the SWF-File within a Shockwave Flash Object.

AS3: Using ExternalInterface

C++: ASInterface (not available) so I searched for a solution...

Browsing the internet I found some code that probably fix my problems.
https://github.com/wy182000/flash-to-directx

All in all I hardly understand this code so it`s impossible for me to integrate the files in my MFC project as well as use this code (what to do for doing this or that). Perhaps you can push me in the right direction even it´s just for "How to include this stuff"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider communicating via sockets/UDP? Implementation should be quite easy on both sides.

Comment: This is the other way but I have to figure out more than one opportunity. Good to know: The first step is that the swf receives data from the C++ part and it`s not only one data model e.g. just Strings. Furthermore, I think I have to write a own parser because C++ can´t stream XML

Comment: You may want to check for RTFMP and AMF C++ implementations, too. Not sure if either one fits to your aimed architecture though.

Comment: Does C++ support RTFMP and AMF or do I need some C++ code snippets???

Comment: Natively this will most probably be not supported - just google a bit for the two terms I floated as suggestion to see if this may help you.